# How to write the code so that car and list aren't in it?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Is there anyway to write the below code as to not have to make a list from which later on we have to car the element?

```
(define (square-it l)
  (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) l))

(define (sum-it l)
  (foldl + 0 l))

(define (sum-of-squares n)
  (sum-it (square-it (numbers n))))

(define (square-of-sum n)
  (square-it (*list* (sum-it (numbers n)))))

(- (*car* (square-of-sum 100)) (sum-of-squares 100))
```

Comment: Perhaps you should do different things than rely on  `square-it` since it's obvious that `(map square lst)` and `(square n)` are different. You really need to explain your problem rather than the problem with the solution you have opted for (XY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sylwester, `square-it` is useful for squaring a list but not for squaring a single value, the inputs and outputs are different in each case, and `sqr` is the right procedure for squaring a single value. This should be enough to fix the problem:

```
(define (square-of-sum n)
  (sqr (sum-it (numbers n))))

(- (square-of-sum 100) (sum-of-squares 100))
```

A simpler solution would be to use [iterations and comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html) and define each procedure independently. We can calculate the values directly over a range of values using only built-in procedures, there's no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
(define (sum-of-squares n)
  (for/fold ([sum 0])
            ([i (in-range n)])
    (+ sum (sqr i))))

(define (square-of-sum n)
  (sqr (apply + (range n))))
```